# Return segment of statement that makes it TRUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

```
H         I       J          K               L                M     

Lenght  Width   Height  Compare_Length  Compare_Width   Compare_Height

3.750   3.750   4.500    3.750           3.750              2.450

5.000   3.875   3.875    5.000           4.000              0.500

5.000   3.875   3.875    5.000           4.000              0.500

5.000   3.750   3.750    5.000           4.000              0.500
```

I have this data, I need to compare all 3 columns Length (H) width (I) and Height (J) to the compare_ Length (K) Compare_width  (L)  and Compare_height (M) column.  Some of the data was entered into the wrong column so the height may correspond to the compare length column etc.  Also, I need to compare the data +/- 1.00 inches, so if a number is within 1 inch it will valuate to TRUE.

here is what I am using.

`=AND(OR((ABS(H3-K3)<=1),(ABS(H3-L3)<=1),(ABS(H3-M3)<=1)),OR((ABS(I3-K3)<=1),(ABS(I3-L3)<=1),(ABS(I3-M3)<=1)),OR((ABS(J3-K3)<=1),(ABS(J3-L3)<=1),(ABS(J3-M3)<=1)))`

The problem I am having is that column H and I obviously match, but J does not correspond with M within 1 inch, which should make the entire equation FALSE.  So the last OR statement in my equation needs to correspond with the remaining cell that doesn't make the other OR statements TRUE.  I am thinking I need to return the equations or cell # that makes the OR statements true, then add in some logic that makes the remaining OR statement only compare the cell that basically hasn't been used yet.

Let me put it in lay-man terms, if column H, I or J match any column in K, L, or M within 1 inch and if all H, I and J correspond to all K, L, and M the equation should valuate to TRUE.

Any help offered would be tremendous!

Comment: For the examples you've given, could you add the expected output ? As it stands I'm not sure exactly what you need.

Comment: row 1 should equate to false

Comment: And the others all evaluate to true?

Comment: these all equate to True. Row 1 SHOULD be false. Row 1 is the one of concern because 2 of the 3 match, but the 3rd column should make the statement false, but since 4.500 is less than 1 inch from 3.75, which already corresponds to the other 2 columns, it makes my equation true.

Comment: Then I'm completely lost. I don't see what the 0.5 is supposed to match in the any of the lines.

Comment: Perhaps add some pictures of what you have and what you expect as well as the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I'm missing something what the OP is looking for. The same requirement was met as below - by doing the same " **STEP BY STEP** ".
[image]

Comment: This helps a TON! What if, though, column H matches column L (like the length and widths were confused when they were entered)?

Comment: then you need to add another column to check if column H & L absolute values matching. This I think will lead us into 9 different combinations. What is the objective of this whole thing?

Comment: Ok, I see, I am comparing the dimensions of items, to see if they are within 1 inch, from 2 different sources.  However, the 2 different source measured the dimensions differently for each item.  I needed another POV because I started confusing myself trying to think it through.